# Converting a plaintext to hex for AES encryption

Tags: aes

Looking through AES process I see it uses a substitution table which need the input in the form of hex. Im wondering if i have a plaintext of 16 bytes such as 'j±…<Ãà!DÈ¶;5˜‰*', how can I convert each of these bytes into hex so they can be used with the subsitution table?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Are you trying to implement AES? If not, the libraries handle it for you. A byte is two hex and a sample AES code will help you. [tiny AES](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c/blob/master/aes.c)

Comment: @kelalaka its for a task, but I am just trying to understand a little more in depth about AES. It seems there is not an easy table or something similar that would tell you the exact HEX value for a byte 'i' and so on

Comment: There't no byte 'i'. There's a character 'i', which can be encoded into a byte via Unicode code point U+0069 as UTF-8, where it's 69. 69 in hex is 45, so 0x45 is one possibility. If it's not UTF-8,  some other value would be used. EG the ancient EBCDIC encoding assigned 0x89 to 'i'.